# Why don't my markers display after switching from version 2 to version 3 of Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

After the transition from version 2 to version 3 of Google Maps, the markers are no longer visible. I can not find the error! Can anyone help me?
The offending page is http://www.lalpinistavirtuale.it/default.asp (below is a Google map where you should see about 200 clickable marker).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your `initialize` function, you have switched the first section of code over to v3, but you have some more work to do:

- `GSize(32,32)` should become: `google.maps.Size( 32, 32)`
- `GPoint(16,32)` should become: `google.maps.Point( 16, 32)`
- `GLatLng(44.1883535,7.41206386)` should become: `google.maps.LatLng( 44.1883535, 7.41206386)`
- `GIcon` creation should be refactored to use: `google.maps.MarkerImage( url, size:Size, origin?:Point, anchor?:Point, scaledSize?:Size )`
- `map.addControl` calls should be refactored into: `MapOptions` properties as follows:

```
var mapOpts = {
    panControl:        true,   // First half of replacing GLargeMapControl
    zoomControl:       true,   // Other half of replacing GLargeMapControl
    scaleControl:      true,   // Replaces GScaleControl
    mapTypeControl:    true    // Replaces GMapTypeControl
};
```

Each of these controls have options that may be set; more details are at the [v3 API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). You may have other v2 code that has to be refactored, but that's the lion's share. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You're createmarker function is using "Gmarker" and in V3 you should be using "google.maps.Marker"